# (react native) java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__emutls_get_address" referenced by

Tags: android, react-native

when upgrading from RN 0.71.6 to 0.72.2 the android build fails with
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__emutls_get_address" referenced by ... lib/arm64/libfolly_runtime.so"...

anyone know how i can solve this?

i've tried

```
`implementation "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5+"
resolutionStrategy {
    force "com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.5+"
}`
```

`pickFirst '**/libjsc.so' pickFirst '**/libfolly_runtime.so'`